# Nuxt 3 , how to build for shard hosting

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I used Vue , when i build

```
npm run build
```

i get a *dist* folder with a *index.html* file , so i can hosted in any hosting ,

now i tried to use **Nuxt** and when i build i dont get an *index.html* file , so i cant deploy on an normal hosting ,

so i thire a way to create a build in Nuxt just like normal Vue ,

please Notice:

- i know that Nuxt provide a free hosing
- i need to build it as SPA app , not as a static pages

Comment: From where do you know that Nuxt provide free hosting?  And if you need simple SPA just use Vue or  Nuxt with `SSR: false`.

Comment: Nuxt don't provide any hosting.

Comment: @nur_riyad Not `SSR:` but `ssr: false` and it not works `generate` works. Keep in mind, it's pre rendered.

Comment: i tried , ssr: false  - and nothing changed ,

Answer (score 0):

The command to build out nuxt is `npm run generate` & builds out to a folder called `.output`.
You will find the `index.html` file in `.output/public`.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/commands/generate#nuxi-generate

Comment: i tried it, the *generate * create a non spa app , the site reloads with each link

Comment: For internal links, you must use `nuxt-link` to achieve page transitions.
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-link#internal-routing

Comment: yes , i used it , but it does not work as SPA when run generate

Comment: I suggest to you this method having built a static SPA nuxt sites my self and guarantee it works. Have you read the get-stated documentation thoroughly? here is anchor link to a step you might have missed on Client-side Only Rendering:
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#client-side-only-rendering